# What is the exact motive of the "yagya" which is done by Rishi-munis?

Tags: rishi, yajna

Rishi-munis did the 'yagya' many times due to an order of his king. they did because fulfil their king's wish. So, was there any benefits or importance for common society people for yagya?

Comment: If no explicit motive (such as an ishti ) is defined , the default motive is loka kalyana i.e., the welfare of all beings and the universe.

Comment: Its for self progress in spiritual and material life as well as attaining sadgati after death.

Comment: That depends upon the type of Yajna